# How to delete some line from .txt file using batch

Tags: batch-file, text

I have a .txt file named Test.txt. The data of the .txt file is like below :

```
Name|Address|Product|Valid
Ali |Perak  |Tekun  |29/01/2015
Abu |Kedah  |Mabrur |05/08/2014
Zai |Perlis |Hayat  |02/03/2018
Kay |KL     |Mabrur |26/07/2019
Mat |PJ     |Mabrur |14/11/2010
```

I need a batch file to delete the data that has Mabrur as a Product. Is this can be done?

Comment: *»I need code«* is not a question, at least according to the rules of Stack Overflow. Hence please read the [tour] and learn [ask] here! Anyway, take a look at [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) as a starting point...

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

```
findstr /v /i /L /c:"Mabrur" text.txt >out.txt
```

should accomplish this - within limits.

`/v` means "lines that do *not* contain

`/i` means "case-insensitive".

*all lines containing the `/L` literal string `Mabrur`, whether it is as product or some other column, or is part of a longer string will be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Find` command:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "fIn=MyData.txt"
If Not Exist "%fIn%" Exit /B
Copy /Y "%fIn%" "%fIn%.bak">Nul 2>&1 || Exit /B
Find /V /I "Mabrur"<"%fIn%.bak">"%fIn%"
::Del "%fIn%.bak"
```

- Change `MyData.txt` on line `2` to your actual file name.
- For future use, if you don't want the original content keeping, you can remove first two characters, `::`, from the last line.
- If you want a case sensitive match you can remove the `/I` option on line `5`

*Enter `Find /?` at the Command prompt for its usage*.

Answer (score -1):

Try `sed -i '/Mabrur/d' ./Test.txt`

This will delete any line that contains `Mabrur`

Comment: sed is not installed by default on the windows system ,so I suppose you should point where it can be downloaded from.

Comment: `set` is not available Windows (natively), and tag [tag:batch-file] implies Windows...